# How should I drag content from one array of JTextFields to another?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, drag-and-drop, jtextfield

I figured out how to drag to highlight multiple cells in a  GridLayout-designed grid (which wasn't too hard) and how to drag a cell from one such grid to another (which involved brute force and math, but it turned out not to be all that hard, either).

But the code looks and feels hacked.

**How should I have done it?**

Here are code fragments that typify what I did to drag content (one `char`):

For each cell in `txtUser[]` grid add mouse listener to identify the cell about to be dragged and also access its content:

```
  txtUser[i].addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseListener() 
  {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {   

      currentUserCell.index = interp(e.getXOnScreen(), ulcUser.x, txtUser[0].getWidth());

      if(txtUser[currentUserCell.index].getText().length() > 0)

        currentUserCell.content = txtUser[currentUserCell.index].getText().charAt(0);
    }
```

Here's `interp()`, which converts from absolute screen pixel (x) to (returned) grid element number, given the upper-left corner of the text field array and the width of one element:

```
  static int interp(int x, int ulc, int w){

    return (x - ulc)/w;
  }
```

If the user moves the frame, `interp()` above doesn't work, requiring need to `reorient()`:

```
  void reorient(){

    ulcGrid = new Point(cells[ 0][ 0].getLocationOnScreen().x, cells[ 0][ 0].getLocationOnScreen().y);
    ulcUser = new Point(txtUser[ 0]  .getLocationOnScreen().x, txtUser[ 0]  .getLocationOnScreen().y);
  }
```

(I tried to use relative pixel locations, but couldn't make it work. I may revisit this.)

In order to drop the dragged content, the destination had better be `inbounds()`:

```
  boolean inbounds(int r, int c){

      return ! (r >= N || c >= N || r < 0 || c < 0);  
  }
```

If inbounds, the letter is dropped, as long as destination is empty:

```
  public  void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    int x, y;

      if(! dragging)
        return;
      dragging = false;

      x =  e.getLocationOnScreen().x;
      y =  e.getLocationOnScreen().y;

      int c = Utilities.interp(x, ulcGrid.x);
      int r = Utilities.interp(y, ulcGrid.y);

      if(! inbounds(r, c))
        return;

      if(cells[r][c].getText().length() > 0)
        return;

      cells[r][c].setText("" + currentUserCell.content);
```

The previous method required a `MouseMotionAdapter` for each cell of the source array.

And it just seems so hacked. One reason I say this is that I rely on several global variables, such as `ulcGrid` and `ulcUser` and `currentUserCell` and `dragging`:

```
  private  void txtUserMouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) 
  {                                         
    dragging = true;
  }
```

I had a nice learning experience, but I'd rather have more-professional-looking code, most notably with fewer global variables. (I realize that a good start would be to not rely on absolute pixel addresses.)

**So I'm asking where to find a better way, specifically how to identify the drag source and destination cells of a one- or two-dimensional array of text fields.**

=================
--EDIT--

My program works. **My question is** about whether there is a library that would make it easier and more reliable than what I've written to drag from the one-dimenional array at the bottom of the screen below onto the large grid.

But now that I've read the comments, maybe this is just another bad question that should be deleted.

[image]

Comment: Consider helping us by making your question easier to answer by creating and posting a [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing this will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you get prompt decent answers.

Comment: *"So I'm asking where to find a better way, specifically how to identify the drag source and destination cells of a one- or two-dimensional array of text fields"* - In this case, there is no "drag source" and scraps of out-of-context code does not illuminate a possible solution...What "might" be better is to use the container (if possible) as the drag source, wrapping the array contents as the transferrable data

Comment: I edited the original post, indicating that my code works and showing what I've succeeded in doing (dragging and dropping), but now that two of you have mentioned it, this is probably a **question worthy of deletion**. I thought that drag-and-drop of cells from one array of text fields to another might be more elegantly done than my brute-force method of mapping pixels to indices. I was looking for a source illustrating this, because no search I've tried has turned up anything relating drag/drop and grids. I know A WAY to do it, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Please be aware that I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: What I meant by "how to identify the `drag` source and destination cells of a one- or two-dimensional array of text fields" would have been made more apparent by omitting the word `drag` while keeping in mind that the source cell is to be dragged to the destination.

Comment: I had not stumbled onto `SetDragEnabled` until just now. (It's in none of my texts.) However, given the particulars of my situation (can only drag "black" letters from the seven cells at the bottom of the screen to non-empty cells on the grid and other "rule-enforcement" complications, such as re-filling the empty box after its contents are dragged), I'm not sure having set `setDragEnabled` would have saved much code. I still wouldn't know which cells were involved, would I?

Comment: You state, `"But now that I've read the comments, maybe this is just another bad question that should be deleted."` -- that wasn't my point at all. My point was that you could make your question a **much better question** by creating and posting a [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read the link to see what I mean.

Comment: _"My question is about whether there is a library that would make it easier and more reliable than what I've written"_ - 1) Asking for third party libraries is generally frowned upon on SO 2) Generally, questions regarding improving code, belong on CodeReview, part of the SE network